# issue adding contact to empty arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I am having working on an andress book program that takes input from user to add/search/display all and remove contacts. I am trying to add a contact to an empty array but the program gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

only when I change the array to be [10], for example, then the program works fine.

```
public Main() {
        database = new String[0];
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        dataCount = 0;

    }
public void add(final String name) {
    if (dataCount <= database.length) {
        database[dataCount] = new String(name);
        dataCount++;
        System.out.println("adding: " + name);
    }

}
```

why is this happening?

Comment: That's not an `ArrayList`. That is an array. Arrays in Java are of fixed size and cannot grow.  Use an `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

that's not how you declare and array.
A string array is declared: arrayType[] nameOfArray new arrayType[arraySize];
Also, you can't have an array of size 0. You can have an array of 1. Remember if you have an array named arr of size x the position arr[x] does not exist but arr[0]-arr[x-1] do exist.